# Salesforce DX, ERROR when retrieving metadata with colon on its name

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, commandline

When doing a `sfdx force:source:pull` command from my scracth org I can't save on my local filesystem a resource that contains "`:`" on it.

I'm running on Windows Environment and the following image shows the error:

[image: Error]

`U:\sfdx_playground_2\geolocation>sfdx force:source:pull -f
ERROR:  UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'U:\sfdx_playground_2\geolocation\force-app\main\default\profiles\Custom: Support Profile.profile-meta.xml'.`

Windows does not accept any file with "`:`"

The following image show the assets that I've changed through browser, you can see that there is 3 profiles that contains "`:`"

[image: Profile listing]

I was able to download only the **Admin** profile, which name does not contain a colon

One interesting point is that on Trailhead correspondent module, the list of changes made on the browser is listed diffent, with the character "`%3A`" replacing the "`:`"

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/sfdx_get_started/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_build_app

As shown below:

[image: Image from correspondent Trailhead Page]

So, maybe there is some workaround for my CLI treat "`:`" as "`%3A`" and then everything goes well

Has anybody come across a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple.

I just renamed the profile name through the browser.

And then I was able to fetch/pull everything properly.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the Windows command prompt get confused about colons in strings before, although running a quick test, it appears to work for me:

[image: Command Prompt sfdx pull]

Couple of things you can try:

1. Update your SFDX  CLI with `sfdx update`
2. Start using Git Bash instead...

**Why Git bash?**

Well, it looks prettier for a start, and it is a closer match functionality-wise to what Mac and Linux users will be using so tutorials and things will need less re-interpretation. Also it doesn't seem to have issues with colons in strings. You also get a load of other quite powerful command line tools with it. Not only that but it tells you what branch you're on in your git repository, which has saved my bacon many a time...

[image: Git Bash prompt]

You probably already have Git Bash if you have installed Git already. If you've not, I would recommend that you do, to make the best use of source/version control with sfdx :)

Comment: Im using Git Bash